# Converting PDF to WMF

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle-designer, wmf

Can someone suggest the best way to convert a PDF file to WMF?

I currently make Dynamic XML Form PDFs with Adobe LiveCycle Designer, but a client requires the file in WMF format for printing. Instead of filling out the form directly, they have their users answer the questions within their own UI, then print the fields to the form.

I've tried converting the PDF to PNG within Acrobat then converting it to WMF, but our client is having issues with them indicating these WMFs "appear to be graphics renamed as WMFs".

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 1):

Try [writing a script that prints your PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462388/programatically-print-multiple-copies-from-command-line) into a WMF/EMF virtual printer.

There a few out there, for example:

- [EMF Printer](http://emfprinter.sourceforge.net/) (GPL, not free for commercial use).
- [Amyuni EMF Printer](http://www.amyuni.com/en/resources/freetools/) Freeware, but a bit outdated (*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies*).

I believe there is another one (as source code) in the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx) source code samples, but I cannot find the link now.

Comment: It seems EMF Printer does not work on 64bit systems: [Feature Request](http://sourceforge.net/p/emfprinter/feature-requests/3/)