# Print multiple copies of pdf from script file

Tags: batch-file, pdf, printing

I would like to silent print a PDF file multiple times. I don't really mind what implementation is used, but due to being in a corporate environment I cannot easily install unsupported software :(.

I am currently using the following VBscript but could switch to any other implementation:

```
    TargetFolder = "<path to folder>" 
 Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
 Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder) 
 Set colItems = objFolder.Items 
 For Each objItem In colItems 
 For i = 1 To 13     
 objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("Print")
 Next 
 Next
```

This spools the job 13 times though. Is there a way to do this as a single job?

I also saw a suggestion for printing using adobe reader that looked like this:

```
AcroRd32.exe /t <file.pdf> <printer_name> <printer_driver> <printer_port>
```

But I couldn't find any reference material for passing the number of copies as a parameter.

Comment: Hint: `For i = 1 To 13`, `Next`.

Comment: The objective is to get the PDF to print 13 times. What I am getting at is that this loop sends the document to the printer 13 separate times (print one, receive it again, print again....repeat). I would like it to send it once and print it 13 times.

Comment: And, **please read tag description! `BATCH-FILE` DOES NOT mean processing multiple files!**

Comment: I'm familiar with what a batch-file is. This is one. It is a set of commands to be executed in a windows environment saved into a single script. While this batch file supports the batch printing of all files in the folder, this has no bearing on the question at hand and the tag is appropriate.

Comment: The 3rd sentence is correct. But isn't this a VBScript. The `AcroRd32.exe` is just a command, and it can run from both **command prompt** and **batch file**.

Comment: And... I wonder... Where is the so-called "Batch File"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this questions which is essentially the same:

[Programatically print multiple copies from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462388/programatically-print-multiple-copies-from-command-line?rq=1)

It appears that looping through and sending the file multiple times is the only solution without additional software.